# php Login Module Doesn't Work

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, web-deployment

I know little bit of php-mysql and web programming. For my project work, i made one login module, it contains two pages but it has some errors. I use WAMP for project, whenever i feed data and press login it does not go to profile.php page and session does not start. It show same page(login.php) after Login Button Pressed From last two days i was searching for this error but i cant solve it. My project have other several pages. Here is my code.

**login.php**

```
    <html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="text.css" ></link>
<title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container" >
<div id="header" style="text-align: center;" >
<table width="500" align="center">
    <tr >
    <img src="logo.jpg"/>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

<div>
<table class="form" align="center"  style="height:200px;padding-left:30px;float-align:center;margin-left=20px;margin-top:40px;margin-bottom:20px;text-align:;padding-left:20px;">
<form action="loginproc.php" method="POST">
<tr>
    <td align="center"colspan="780px" >
    <h3 style="font-family:Calibri; font-size: 22pt;font-weight: bold; color:#3B8C8C;text-align: center;">LOGIN</h3></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Email ID</td>
    <td><input type="email" name="emailid" maxlength="50" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="pwd" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" align="center" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Login" style="margin-bottom:20px;margin-top:20px;"/>
    <input type="reset" name="reset" class="button" value="Reset" style="margin-bottom:20px;margin-top:20px;"/>
</tr>   
</form></table></div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**loginproc.php**

```
 <?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
$server="localhost";
$user="root";
$password="";
$db="utility";
$con = mysql_connect($server,$user,$password);
if(!$con) 
{
    die("Cannot Connect".mysql_error());
}
else
    {
    if(!mysql_select_db($db,$con))
    {
    header('Location: login.php');
    }
    else
    {
    $email = isset($_POST['emailid'])? $_POST['emailid']:"";
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);

    $password = isset($_POST['pwd'])? $_POST['pwd']:"";
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

    $access = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE (email = '$email') AND (password = '$password')";
    $access = mysql_query($access);
    $accessrow = mysql_num_rows($access);

    if($accessrow == 1)
    {
        include('session.php');
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        header('Location: profile.php');
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location: home.php');   
    }
    mysql_close($con);
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Since you say that it's showing 'login.php', and that's not one of the two pages that should be shown, I'd say your redirect isn't working.  That seems possible if the connection fails (or if your code is just bad).

Comment: Ya I have same doubt, redirect is not working but the same style of code is used in registration module and it work perfectly. Is it any error in session management in code ?

Comment: Does home.php redirect to login.php if the user is not logged in?

Comment: echo your sql query `echo $access;` right after you create it and before `$access = mysql_query($access); `.  check and ensure your query looks right.

Answer (score 0):

In your code posted, you have a leading space, which would prevent your session from starting since the session cookie has to be set before any output.

```
*SPACE*<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
```

Is that space an error in your post, or is that what you really have in your login.php file?

Comment: Sorry it is error in my post , actual file does not contain space

Comment: Does your PHP error log have any errors in it in response to your form submission?

Answer (score 0):

check the DB connection and this line `if(!mysql_select_db($db,$con))`
just so you know, use MySQLi or PDO_MySQL instead of MySQL as its deprecated.

Comment: I had check DB Connection Its working fine. The same style of code is used for Registration Module (register.php & dataentry.php). Now the Registration Module work perfectly, Data add to Database successfully.

Comment: try changing `include('session.php');` to `include 'session.php`;`

Answer (score 0):

Your code executed here

```
if(!mysql_select_db($db,$con))
{
header('Location: login.php');
}
```

May be the given database is not present, that's why `login.php` page is showing.Check your database.

And try to arrange your `HTML` code properly. You used `Form` inside `Table`.

It should be like this

```
<form>
    <table>
        // your code..
    </table>
</form>
```